# Combine two Java projects in Android Studio

Tags: android, project

I am helping kids with a school project.  We have two Java projects, A & B. For Project A, I just need it to run some camera vision code  and return an integer value. For Project B, where most of my code will be, I would like to call Project A and use the integer value returned by it. What is the best way to organize them? Also should I create a public integer in Project A to capture the returned value? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually orgnize projects by using build tools named 'Gradle' in AndroidStudio. You can create two Module(Module-A & Module-B) in a project in AndroidStudio to include your own java code source. because you want to use code in project-B from project-A, so we called this '*B dependsOn A*'.In gradle,we implement this by doing so:

add this script to the Module-B's build script which named build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
...
implementation project(':Module-A')
}
```

now you can directly use the java code in Module-A.

and be attention that Module-A's plugin id of gradle is `com.android.library`,
You can refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html